# Google Apps Script - Retrieving username

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This will hopefully be an easy one for you experienced developers. I'm trying to use the Google Apps Script service to get the username of the logged in user for my Google Site. I can get the email to display fine, however when I try to use the substring method to shorten to the username I get the follow error.

> TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object email@email.com. (line 4, file "getusername")

I understand why I'm getting this error but not sure how to fix it. Below is my code

```
    function doGet() {

  var userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var username = userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf("@"));

  var HTMLString= "<body> <h2> Logged in as " + userEmail +",</h2></body>";

    HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
  return HTMLOutput
}
```

I'm guessing that because the variable `userEmail` is dynamic depending on the logged in user, the variable `username` is unable to see the email address until it has executed ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Complete Javascript newbie here.

Thanks

Jack

Comment: You're trying to shorten an object, rather than a string. See [@SandyGood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429226/5463636) for a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser();
```

to:

```
var userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
```

If you look at the documentation for `Session.getEffectiveUser()`, you'll see what the "return" is.  I never paid much attention to that for a long time.  But, you need to always know what is returned.  Some return types are: string, or an object, or an integer, or a Class.  Depending upon what is returned, that will determine what you can further do.  Lots of beginners notice that there is a period in between things, and are able to figure out that they need to patch things together with a period.  But they don't really know what that period is for.  That period is called a dot operator, and every place there is a "dot operator" is basically another step in a process.  You're "chaining" multiple operations together.  In the code: `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`  there are two periods (dot operators) and two separate things happening, each with a different returned value.  The `getEmail()` method returns a string.  The documentation states that `getEffectiveUser()` returns a "User"  But if you go to the documentation for "User" you'll see it described as a "Class".  To understand what a "Class" is, you'll need to do some research.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed :D Any chance you could explain why that worked ? Thanks again.

Comment: @JackSmith Why what worked? Using a method of the object to access a property of the object? That's just what methods do. [`User#getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) returns the value of the `email` property for the given `User` object.

Comment: See added explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation @SandyGood Really appreciated :D

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct by clicking the big green check mark.